# missing profile for a server adapter in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-web-start

I am trying to set up a dynamic web project in Eclipse 2018-12. Within the Java EE perspective, the lower panel is hosting several commonly used views (markers, console, snippets, search ), among which the Servers view offers the possibility to bind the current project to an already existing server.

If no such server is defined, this view is showing a quick link to "add new server. When one is about to define a new server, a creation wizard takes off, and the first window you get is the profile select window. I would like to set up a Tomcat server, but my initial list does not include Apache Tomcat at all.

Question: how am I supposed top populate the initial list with a desired web server profile template ?

Comment: How did you install this? You seem to be missing the JST Server Adapters Extensions feature, which is the one that contains the Tomcat support. https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F

Answer (score 0):

I have searched for Eclipse download links and the first link (and the only one shown there) on the Eclipse Foundation page was Eclipse 2018-12. It seemed pretty good at the time. Now the same page shows Eclipse 2019-06 (64-bits).

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the current intallation with the JST Server Adapter Extensions did the job nicely. Thank you nitind !